# How to allow alphabets only in EditText Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-xml-attribute

I need to allow alphabets only using EditText (like name) but it's allowing numeric values also

I give `FieldType.TEXT_PERSON_NAME -> etField.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME` or `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS`  (like `android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords"`
) but it's still allow numeric values. I need to allow alphabets only (like name)

Comment: You can use the digits flag to specify allowed characters:
android:digits="abcd"

Comment: already i tried that one. it's not working

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to allow only alphabets in an EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/your_id"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

This will allow the user to enter only lowercase, uppercase letters and spaces. If you want to allow special characters or non-English letters, then you can add them to the `android:digits` list.